# C++: how to do I/O for nonblocking socket

Tags: c++, sockets, nonblocking

Good day. So, i have socket:

```
if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &this->wsaData) != 0)
    throw(errors::WSASTARTUP);

if ((this->serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    throw(errors::SOCKET_CREATING);

this->serverSocketAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
this->serverSocketAddr.sin_port = htons(this->port);
this->serverSocketAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

if (bind(this->serverSocket, (sockaddr*)&this->serverSocketAddr, sizeof(this->serverSocketAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    throw(errors::SOCKET_BINDING);

if (listen(this->serverSocket, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    throw(errors::SOCKET_LISTENING);

u_long mode = 1;

if (ioctlsocket(this->serverSocket, FIONBIO, &mode) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    throw (errors::SOCKET_NONBLOCK);
```

And try to read incoming messages like this:

```
std::string receive(SOCKET s) {
    char buff[BUFF_SIZE];
    int nOfReceivedBytes = 0;
    nOfReceivedBytes = recv(s, buff, BUFF_SIZE, NULL);

    if ((nOfReceivedBytes = recv(s, buff, BUFF_SIZE, NULL)) > 0) {
        printMessage("Number of received bytes: %d\n", nOfReceivedBytes);
    }
    else if (nOfReceivedBytes == 0) {
        printMessage("Connection is closed.\n");
        return "";
    }
    else if (nOfReceivedBytes < 0 && errno != EWOULDBLOCK) {
        printMessage("Receive failed.\n");
        return "";
    }

    if (nOfReceivedBytes < BUFF_SIZE)
        buff[nOfReceivedBytes] = '\0';

    return std::string(buff);
}
```

When i exec `receive()` step by step, i have nice received messages without any errors.

But if i do this without debug, i have `errno == 1` here

```
    else if (nOfReceivedBytes < 0 && errno != EWOULDBLOCK) {
        printMessage("Receive failed.\n");
        return "";
    }
```

Without calling `ioctlsocket()` it works great. How to fix it?

Comment: What do you expect to accomplish by calling `recv()` twice, and discarding the results of the first `recv()` call? And when all that logic falls through in case of `EWOULDBLOCK`, and `nOfReceivedBytes` is -1, what do you think `buff[nOfReceivedBytes] = '\0';` is going to do?

Comment: Set `errno = 0` before each call to `recv()`. If it doesn't fix anything, please try and give us a [mcve].

Comment: @SamVarshavchik overepic calling recv() twice, remove second, thank you. But error still exists. And about `buff[nOfReceivedBytes] = '\0'`: i have changed it to this: `else if (nOfReceivedBytes < 0 && errno != NO_ERROR && errno != EWOULDBLOCK) {...}`

Comment: @YSC i've changed errno to 0 and it always with this value. But error exists. How can i add a visual studio solution here? And some error can be with this `send(s, m.c_str(), m.length(), NULL);`. I call this func on server side. Possible, third parameter `flags` should be not NULL. Client not recv anything and gives me error on receiving with

Comment: Well what is errno in the failure cases? Get the value and work from there. Maybe you aren't handling all possibilities.

Comment: There is no guarantee whatsoever that send() will send the requested number of bytes. See its documentation. You must check its return value.

Comment: I've fixed this, just changed logic of message reseiving. Thank you guys!